# translation cannot work with symfony2.1

Tags: layout, configuration, routes, translation, symfony-2.1

have a problem with translation is Symfony2.1
I tried almost all methods provided in the symfony_book but, only the translation from english to frensh that works, the reverse doesn't work
here is my routing.yml

```
_acceuil:
pattern:  /{_locale}/acceuil/
defaults: { _controller: gestionConferenceApplicationBundle:acceuil:acceuil, _locale: en }
requirements:
  _locale: en|fr|de
```

is my layout page I have thoses to links that allaw to switch between langage:

```
<a  style="padding-top: -10px;" href="{{ path('_acceuil', {'_locale': 'fr' }) }}" >FRANCAIS</a>
        <a  style="padding-top: -10px;" href="{{ path('_acceuil', {'_locale': 'en' }) }}" >ANGLAIS</a>
```

and this line for test

```
{{ 'welcome in my site'|trans }}
```

and here is my messages.fr.xlf

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>welcome in my site</source>
                <target>bienvenue dans mon site</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

and here is my messages.en.xlf

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>bienvenue dans mon site</source>
                <target>welcome in my site</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

and here is the part wwe are interested in my config.yml :

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallback: en }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: "%kernel.debug%"
form:            true
csrf_protection: true
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:      { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  en
trust_proxy_headers: false # Whether or not the Request object should trust proxy headers (X_FORWARDED_FOR/HTTP_CLIENT_IP)
session:         ~
```

and when I run I have always :

```
bienvenue dans mon site
```

how can I achieve that

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know why your translations don't work.

Because the translation `source` is still this same. It's string from your template.

So ex:

```
{{'My Trans'|trans()}}
```

messages catalogues shoudl look like this fr:

```
'My Trans': 'My trans FR'
```

and the en trans:

```
'My Trans': 'My trans EN'
```

I hope this example will help you.